# C#: why can I not create a system namespace?

Tags: c#

I remember few weeks ago when I reorgnized our code and created some namespaces in our project I got error and the system did not allow me to create a `companyName.projectName.System` namespace, I had to change it to `companyName.projectName.Systeminfo`. I don't know why. I know there is a `System` namespace  but it is not `companyName.projectName.System`. I think `A.B.C` namespace should be different with `A.A.C` namespace. Right?

**EDIT**

The error I got is like the this:

```
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'MyCompany.SystemSoftware.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\workspace\SystemSoftware\SystemSoftware\obj\Release\src\startup\App.g.cs 39  39  SystemSoftware
```

Comment: What was the error you received?

Comment: cannot remember but i will try again to see what's the error is.

Comment: It give me several looks unrelated errors like this: 
Error 7 The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'MyCompany.SystemSoftware.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\workspace\SystemSoftware\SystemSoftware\obj\Release\src\startup\App.g.cs 39 39 SystemSoftware

Comment: A couple people already told you the answer, so I'll just put it in a comment to address your edit: your other `System.Windows.Forms.Label` type declarations are being expanded to `MyCompany.SystemSoftware.System.Windows.Forms.Label`, etc, which are not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're experiencing a namespace clash.

If you name the last part of your namespace System, then the compiler will have a hard time determining if you're referring to the (Microsoft) System namespace or an inner System namespace at your current level (or even an System class or property or ...).

You'll experience the same problem with class names and namespace parts. You can't create a class called System for the same reasons.

Unless you feel like specifying full namespaces for all of your instances.

Answer (score 5):

The code below compiles and runs, so I think you'll need to give us a bit more detail as there's no reason you can't create a namespace such as `companyName.projectName.System` as far as I'm aware.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = new ConsoleApplication1.Project.System.Something();
        }
    }
}
namespace ConsoleApplication1.Project.System
{
    public class Something
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error (the namespace does not exist) when I try to reference something specific like `System.IO.File` if I change my namespace to `ConsoleApp.System`.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you can use relative namespaces in .NET.

if you have an object in the namespace A.B.C, then when you are coding in the namespace A.B, you can refer to that object as just C.ObjectName, instead of A.B.C.ObjectName.  Therefore, if you were at the companyName.projectName level, System would be abiguous, unelss you were to start using namespace aliases.

However, I found the best approach is to avoid the thing that is causing the confusion in the first place, and change your System namespace to something else, and it all ceases to be a continuing problem.

Answer (score 0):

C# can only get confused. Please read the following [topic on Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx). I know that he speaks about classes and namespaces, but the same or other related behaviour may occur.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Lippert just posted on a closely related issue.  http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

By creating x.y.System for code in the x.y namespaces it becomes difficult to determine if you are referring to x.y.System.Foo or System.Foo.

I would come up with a different name for the sake of clarity.